# Process native events of a window created by QQmlApplicationEngine

Tags: qt, qml, qtquickcontrols2

There is [QWidget::nativeEvent](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#nativeEvent) for widget windows.

Is there some analogue for windows created by `QML`?

I want to process some messages of main window (`ApplicationWindow`).

Main window is created by `QML` code which is loaded by `QQmlApplicationEngine`.

Should I use [QCoreApplication::installNativeEventFilter](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#installNativeEventFilter)?

Comment: Yes, use QCoreApplication::installNativeEventFilter

Comment: OK, should I delete this question then?

Comment: I do not know, it depends on you, for me you have 2 options: you delete it or publish an answer, your choice. :)